# How to set Array in StoredProcedureQuery..setParameter()?

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, stored-procedures, java-stored-procedures

There is a code like this:

```java
StoredProcedureQuery query = this.em.createStoredProcedureQuery ("NameOfProcedure");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter ("list_of_ids", Array.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.setParameter (Parameters.PIECE_IDS, oracleArray (dataSource, "T_NUMBER_LIST", request.getItems (). toArray (items)));
```

For eclipslink, this code is successfully executed: a parameter is registered to pass the id list, and then this list is set. In case of Hibernate, an exception of type:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Type cannot be null is thrown

As I understand it, Heber doesn't like Array.class in
`query.registerStoredProcedureParameter ("list_of_ids", Array.class, ParameterMode.IN);`

I tried to fix this section to `Integer []. Class` and `ArrayList.class`, but this leads to other errors, such as:

> Bind value [oracle.sql.ARRAY@5f82399f] was not of specified type [class [Ljava.lang.Integer;

or

> Internal conversion failed: [512]

How do I pass a list to parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate doesn't play nicely with SQL arrays.  You have to create a `UserType` for the array and use that instead.  At the end of this post is an example of creating a `UserType` for a Postgres array.  The same thing should work for Oracle.

https://thorben-janssen.com/mapping-arrays-with-hibernate/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But I don't understand how I should use the custom UserType for StoredProcedureQuery. My procedure returns nothing and I don't have an Entity for it. Any ideas?

Comment: IIUC there isn't a way how to use UserType for stored procedure, there is simply nowhere to express the binding. Afaik custom type with stored procedures is not possible in jpa.